# URL target in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have got 2 applications.

There is a hyperlink in the first application A when i click that it takes me to the 2nd application B, to go back from B > A i have button in the navigation bar which has to take me to exact page in application A from where i clicked to go to the B application. Now when i click on the hyperlink in A application the page number, email are stored in a table.

Now i have to go to page in application A by reading email and page number from the table.

Thanks

Rakesh

Comment: I didn't understand what are you trying to do or what is your question!! can you demonstrate your question on apex.oracle.com

Comment: Further detail in cross-post https://community.oracle.com/thread/4280661